# Copy All PDFs in a folder and all subfolders to a new folder using R

Tags: r, file, pdf, directory

I have nearly 2500 subfolders with `.PDF` files created by `EndNote` reference.

How can I Copy All PDFs in these subfolders to a new single folder?

I want to transfer them to `Zotero`.

The only programming language I am familiar with is R. Can I do this in R?

If not Python - I can google how to run script.

Could someone assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `list.files` you can get complete path of all the pdf files in the main folder as well as sub folders. Then use `file.copy` to copy all the pdf files to new folder (called `New_folder` here).

```
all_pdf <- list.files('main/folder', pattern = '\\.pdf$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
file.copy(all_pdf, 'New_folder/')
```

Comment: OMG! Fabulous. Fantastic. Thanks a heap, Ronak <3    Alternatively, can I use the grep function for this kind of task?

Comment: You mean R's `grep` function to filter files with specific name? You can use that but mostly that can be handled with `pattern` argument in `list.files`.

Comment: Thank you, Ronak. Really appreciate your help. It's almost transferred now. Happy New Year mate! Stay safe and blessed!